# Android application keeps force closing when in background, even if not started, especially at device lock/reopen

Tags: android, google-maps, gps

Hope I don't get many downvotes for this question, but I really don't know how to ask or where to look for this problem. I have an Android app which uses the following services: GPS, Parse.com database, Google Maps.

The problem is, that, after i use it, and exit the app(or leave it in background), everytime after i close and reopen the screen, it says that "it has stopped working". I have no ideea where to look.

Tell me what to provide, and i will!(providing the whole code if necessary).

Thanks!

Comment: Show logcat. and related code where logcat shows error

Comment: The problem is that is does not. It is not connected to the computer when it does that. I'll try anyway.

Answer (score 0):

The services you're using have a lot of run-in-background options like `findInBackground()` and `saveInBackground()` in *Parse* and getting location updates using GPS.

You should stop any such services (unless their running in background after your app exits is the intended behaviour) when you exit your app (say, by overriding `onDestroy()`).

I once created an app that displayed location update Toasts even after I exited the app because I forgot to remove the location updates.

This code may be useful as an example to you:

---

if(mLocationClient!=null && (mLocationClient.isConnected() || mLocationClient.isConnecting()))
        {
            mLocationClient.removeLocationUpdates(this);
            mLocationClient.disconnect();
        }

---

I call this on `onDestroy()` to stop getting updates when I exit the app.

Comment: May i ask what is mLocationClient?

Comment: Sorry for the late response. `mLocationClient` is an instance of `com.google.android.gms.location.LocationClient` that I use in my app to fetch the user's location. I used it as an example of a service that runs in the background.

It would help if you shared your code, maybe.